# Add prometheus static labels to masstransit metrics

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, prometheus, masstransit

I am using the "MassTransit.Prometheus" NuGet package to add metrics to my Asp.net core project.
Now I need to add some static labels to those metrics but could not find a suitable way to do it.
Note: I prefer to keep using the default "UsePrometheusMetrics" extension and don't create custom metrics.
Will somebody advise a solution?

Comment: I'm not a user of this package, however can't you just add your custom label directly on the job configuration ? That's the way it's usually done. Unless I didn't understand the question and you want to add different custom label depending on the metric ?

Answer (score 1):

The MassTransit.Prometheus package uses the prometheus.net library. You should be able to set the static labels that you want by calling the function Metrics.DefaultRegistry.SetStaticLabels as described here: https://github.com/prometheus-net/prometheus-net#static-labels